# Redux component being rendered/called multiple times erroneously?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having a craaaaazy problem. Here is the structure of the app. A `RestaurantContainer` renders a `RestaurantInput` which has a form to grab the name of a restaurant. The restaurants are rendered with `Restaurant` components in a `Restaurants` listing component. The code for these 3 components is at the bottom of this post.

My problem is that when the store contains any restaurants, I get this error:

(Note: this error behavior happens whether I'm adding a restaurant using the form via a dispatch action, OR if I give the `RestaurantContainer` a starting state containing a restaurant – see the commented line in `mapStateToProps`)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Restaurants.render
src/components/restaurants/Restaurants.js:12
   9 | return (
  10 |   <ul>
  11 |     Your Restaurants:
> 12 |     {this.props.restaurants.map(restaurant => {
  13 |       return <Restaurant key={restaurant.id} restaurant={restaurant} />;
  14 |       // <li key={restaurant.id}>{restaurant.name}</li>
  15 |     })}
```

If I swap out the `<Restaurant>` component call for the commented `li`, it works fine.

So, I try to figure out why this is happening and here's where it gets crazy. You'll see the logger statements in the render function of `Restaurants` and elsewhere. Here's what happens in the console when I load the app, with a restaurant already in the state:

```
mapStateToProps
RestaurantsContainer props: {restaurants: Array(1), addRestaurant: ƒ, deleteRestaurant: ƒ}
Restaurants this Restaurants {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
Restaurants props {restaurants: Array(1)}
Restaurants this Restaurants {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
Restaurants props {restaurant: {…}}
Restaurants this Restaurants {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
Restaurants props {restaurant: {…}}
```

You'll see that the `RestaurantsContainer` is rendered once, as expected, but the `Restaurants` component is rendered three times, in some very strange ways.

The first time, its `this` and `props` are both what you'd expect them to be for `Restaurants`. (`{restaurants: Array(1)}`)

However, the second and third times, `this` is what it should be for `Restaurants`, while **`props` is what you'd expect in `Restaurant` (singular).** (`{restaurant: {…}}`)

Finally, I will note that under no circumstances listed does a breakpoint inside of `Restaurant` ever get hit. Also I've tried commenting out the entire return value of `Restaurant`'s `render`, with no improvement.

Here is the code for the components:

```js
// RestaurantsContainer

import React, { Component } from "react";
import RestaurantInput from "../components/restaurants/RestaurantInput";
import Restaurants from "../components/restaurants/Restaurants";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class RestaurantsContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("RestaurantContainer props:", this.props);

    return (
      <div>
        <RestaurantInput
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          addRestaurant={this.props.addRestaurant}
        />
        <Restaurants restaurants={this.props.restaurants} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("mapStateToProps");
  return {
    restaurants: state.restaurants
    // restaurants: [{id: 1, name: "burger king"}]
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addRestaurant: name => dispatch({ type: "ADD_RESTAURANT", name: name }),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(RestaurantsContainer);
```

```js
// Restaurants 

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Restaurant from "./Restaurants";

class Restaurants extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Restaurants this", this);
    console.log("Restaurants props", this.props);

    return (
      <ul>
        Your Restaurants:
        {this.props.restaurants.map(restaurant => {
          return <Restaurant key={restaurant.id} restaurant={restaurant} />;
          // <li key={restaurant.id}>{restaurant.name}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Restaurants;
```

```js
// Restaurant

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReviewsContainer from '../../containers/ReviewsContainer'

class Restaurant extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li>{this.props.restaurant.name}</li>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Restaurant;
```

Comment: Could you post your reducer? I believe the problem is there since you only get the error when updating the state

Comment: Is it possible that you are messing with the import statement in the restaurants component ? import Restaurant from "./Restaurants";

Comment: @jgoday you are ABSOLUTELY right, that is completely the problem and I even understand how that caused the exact problem that occurred!!! THANK YOU!!!!!